# GRAILS -Oracle ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, grails

I have already execute the below query in order to create the table ACCOUNT in my Oracle DB:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT

( TESTACC   VARCHAR2(13 BYTE)             NOT NULL,
  TEST        VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)           DEFAULT 'TEST',

   CONSTRAINT TEST_PK
   PRIMARY KEY
   (TESTACC)

  )
```

Then I create a GRAILS domain

```
class Account {

String testAcc
String test

static constraints = {  
    testAcc     nullable: false 
 }

static mapping = {
    table "ACCOUNT"
    id                      name: "testAcc"
    testAcc                 column: "ID"
    test                    column: "TEST"

}
```

Now, I am trying to execute the query below in GRAILS console :

```
Account.executeQuery("select u.test from Account u")
```

But I facing this issue :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: ORA-00904: "ACCOUNT"."TEST": invalid identifier
```

Comment: yes it is a typo, it is updated now

Comment: Are you connected to the same user as you have created table with?

Comment: yes, the same user

Comment: The table already contains data, so I wonder if some constraints are missing  especially when we talk about nullable

Answer (score 0):

The domain entity Account is poorly defined.

Try this:

```
class Account {

    String testacc
    String test

    static constraints = {  
        testacc     maxSize:13
        test        nullable: true, blank: true, maxSize:3 
    }

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned', name: "testacc", type: 'string'
    }
}
```

In your code `table "ACCOUNT"` and `test column: "TEST"` are redundant.

Also keep in mind that when you define `String testAcc` GORM will try to find (or create) TEST_ACC column.